# Jenkins: define custom mime-type for viewing archived artifacts

Tags: jenkins

I am saving certain log-files during a Jenkins build as archived artefacts within jenkins (e.g. via Jenkinsfile's "archiveArtifacts" command). These files are plain-text-files but unfortunately don't end in ".log". The web.xml of the jenkins.war seems to by default use the octet-stream mime-type for unknown extensions. This leads to the "problem" that i cannot open these logs in the browser easily; rather, chrome downloads the file.
I would like to be able to open the file in the browser for convenience.
Is there a way or plugin to configure/register custom mime-types?

I already tried to modify the web.xml just for a quick hack but did not continue when i noticed that the jars are signed and jenkins does not start when the war-file is modified. So, i rather do not want to go this route; also because i will have to patch the war-file after each and every jenkins-update.

Is there a smarter way? What is not an option for me is to rename my log-files to have an extension like ".log" (which Jenkins will serves as text/plain).

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: In 2023, I have the same problem with HTML files attached to the build. They are displayed as plain text, despite ".html" extension. Jenkins does not even try to guess the correct content type, and I don't know how to set it manually.